# Using OpenGL Vertex Buffer Objects with Dynamically linked OpenGL from Windows

Tags: windows, opengl, dynamic-linking

I am working on setting up a basic OpenGL application by dynamically linking the opengl32.dll file pre-packaged with Windows (That part is non-optional). However I am having quite a lot of difficulty getting procedure addresses for the functions related to Vertex Buffer Objects.

My initial investigations have revealed that windows only exposes the OpenGL 1.1 specification at first, and wglGetProcAddress calls need to be used to get any functions more recent than that. So I modified my code to attempt that method as well. I am using glGenBuffers as my example case, and have attempted four different attempts to load it, and all fail. I have also used glGetString to check my version number which is reported as major version 4, so I doubt it lacks VBO support.

How should I be getting the proc addresses for these VBO functions?

A minimized example of the code I'm dealing with is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

//Load openGL and get necessary functions
HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("opengl32.dll");
PROC WINAPI(*winglGetProcAddress)(LPCSTR);
void(*genBuffers)(int, unsigned int*);

if(hDLL)
{
    winglGetProcAddress = (PROC WINAPI(*)(LPCSTR))GetProcAddress(hDLL, "wglGetProcAddress");
    if(winglGetProcAddress == NULL){cout << "wglGetProcAddress not found!" << endl; return 0;}

    genBuffers = (void(*)(int, unsigned int*))GetProcAddress(hDLL, "glGenBuffers");
    if(genBuffers == NULL){genBuffers = (void(*)(int, unsigned int*))winglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");}
}
else
{cout << "This application requires Open GL support." << endl; return 0;}

//glGenBuffers not supported, fallback to glGenBuffersARB
if(genBuffers == NULL)
{
    genBuffers = (void(*)(int, unsigned int*))GetProcAddress(hDLL, "glGenBuffersARB");
    if(genBuffers == NULL){genBuffers = (void(*)(int, unsigned int*))winglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffersARB");}
    if(genBuffers == NULL)
    {cout << "Could not locate glGenBuffers or glGenBuffersARB in opengl32.dll." << endl; return 0;}
}

//get a Vertex Buffer Object
unsigned int a[1];
genBuffers(1, a);

//cleanup
if(!FreeLibrary(hDLL))
{cout << "Failed to free the opengl32.dll library." << endl;}

return 0;
}
```

When run, it loads the library and get's the wglGetProcAddress correctly, but then outputs the "Could not locate glGenBuffers or glGenBuffersARB in opengl32.dll." error, indicating it failed to get either "glGenBuffers" or "glGenBuffersARB" using either "GetProcAddress" or "wglGetProcAddress".

Alternatively, if this does mean I do not have VBO support, will a driver update help, or is it even possible to get it supported? I'd really rather not use deprecated immediate mode calls.

I am running this in Code::Blocks, on Windows XP, Intel Core i5, with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460.

Comment: This process is [thoroughly covered in the OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions). You shouldn't be loading `opengl32.dll` dynamically anyway; just link to `opengl32.lib` like everyone else. That way, you can use a [proper loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) and not have to bother with this manual loading of functions. Also, note that the process *starts* with creating an OpenGL context. You can't just load a DLL and expect to get functions.

Comment: @Nicol: In the source you quoted in the Windows section about wglGetProcAddress where it says "This function only works in the presence of a valid OpenGL context" was exactly what I needed. I was calling this method prior to setting up the OpenGL context (unaware that it was necessary). Thank you very much, and I appreciate the suggestion of "don't do it dynamically" but that decision is not mine to make. Thanks again for guiding me to my answer.

Comment: How is that decision not yours to make? If your boss/whatever is forcing you to do it, explain to them that it doesn't make any difference whether you manually load the DLL or load it with an import library. And if they can't understand that, then look for a better job.

Comment: It is one of the clients requirements for a variety of poorly-explained reasons that are evidently non-negotiable. So far it has not been particularly difficult to manually load the procedures, and only a subset is needed, so it is not a battle worth fighting. Thanks again for the help though.

Comment: "So far it has not been particularly difficult to manually load the procedures" It's not about loading procedures anymore; you're dealing with OpenGL now. Virtually every OpenGL loading library *requires* linking to the import library; that's simply how almost every OpenGL program works. Which means that you're going to have to *manually* load all of your function pointers. As someone who's written an [OpenGL loading library](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html), all I can say is, "Good luck with that." And I at least had automated code-generation on my side.

Comment: The function pointer loading is largely repetitive and copy-paste-able, or perhaps even macro-able (not sure how many functions I'll need yet, if it'd be worth Macro-ing). And beyond that it's just using the functions as you would if they were otherwise loaded. The values of enums and constants will be a bit of challenge I'll admit (hard-coding them right now) but the deadline is fairly flexible, and the price is right.

Comment: @StrangeQuark: You need about 350 to 400 functions, depending on the function set you're interested in. And like Nicol Bolas already said: Don't attempt to load opengl32.dll manually. There's absolutely no reason for this. There's only one opengl32.dll for Windows and there's no need to dynamically choose which to load. Tell your boss, that loading opengl32.dll manually is a waste of time, introduces a huge amount of problems, but doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: He knows it'll take longer. I can't think of any of these other problems you're suggesting. What are some of the other potential problems I may not be considering? It might help me make a case.